# Resample Landsat 8 to 60m Resolution

Tags: envi, landsat, landsat-8

I have two Landsat images for the same study area. One of them in 1975 (Landsat 2 MSS with 60m resolution) and the other in 2014 (Landsat8 OLI with 30m resolution). I want to do change detection between them. As you know in order to do change analysis on images with different resolutions, I should make them all the same resolution so they match. Since Landsat 8 is higher resolution from Landsat 2. So, I need to do resample for scene of Landsat 8 to to match the MSS data and to compute the change detection.

So please, currently I am working on ENVI 5.1 software. How can I resample the Landsat 8 and do change detection between two satellite images in this software?

Comment: I'm confused - you say you are using ENVI and ERDAS, for which you have no tags, yet you have a tag for [tag:arcgis-desktop] of which you make no mention in your question body.  Can you use the **edit** button to clarify precisely what you are asking, please?

Comment: I've made an edit to add the appropriate software tag and clean up the grammar a little. One thing I want to point out just in case, it appeared you reversed the numbers for the two resolutions. Landsat 8 should be 30m, not 60m.

Comment: Thank you very much for your informative reply and your time is highly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if it will solve your problem or not, but according to [this help page](http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/RasterLayers.html), under the Map Information heading, ENVI will set the map resolution to match the first image added, and reproject (including resample) subsequently added images to match on the fly for the project. This means you can run your analysis without altering the original rasters. Note the order the images are added determines which resolution is used.